# Flutter: Handle both GestureDetector for LongPressed and LongPressDraggable

Tags: flutter, gesture

I want to display the menu when I longpressed an item, and then close the menu and move the item if dragging starts, like the icons on the **iPhone home screen**.I also want to reorder items.

I wrote the code using `LongPressDraggable` and `GestureDetector`.

The problem is that the item starts moving instead of displaying the menu when I longpress an item.If I set `maxSimultaneousDrags` parameter of LongPressDraggable to 0, I can display the menu but I can't move the item.

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SampleContainer()));

class SampleContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class Content {
  final num;
  final IconData icon;

  Content(this.num, this.icon);
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  Size? buttonSize;
  Offset? buttonPosition;
  bool isMenuOpen = false;

  List<Content> data = [
    Content(0, Icons.filter_1),
    Content(1, Icons.filter_2),
  ];

  _swapData(int index1, var index2) {
    Content data1 = data[index1];
    Content data2 = data[index2];
    data[index1] = data2;
    data[index2] = data1;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void openMenu(GlobalKey _key) {
    findButton(_key);
    _overlayEntry = _overlayEntryBuilder();
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlayEntry!);
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  void closeMenu() {
    _overlayEntry!.remove();
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  findButton(GlobalKey _key) {
    RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    buttonSize = renderBox.size;
    buttonPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }

  LongPressDraggable buildDraggable(String name, Content content) =>
      new LongPressDraggable(
        data: content.num,
        maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
        child: Icon(
          content.icon,
          size: 90,
        ),
        onDragStarted: () {
          if (isMenuOpen) {
            closeMenu();
          }
        },
        feedback: Icon(
          content.icon,
          size: 90,
        ),
      );

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntryBuilder() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: buttonPosition!.dy + buttonSize!.height,
          left: buttonPosition!.dx,
          width: buttonSize!.width,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  DragTarget buildDragTarget(Content content) => new DragTarget(
        builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
          GlobalKey _key = LabeledGlobalKey(content.num.toString());
          return GestureDetector(
              key: _key,
              onLongPress: (details) {
                if (isMenuOpen) {
                  closeMenu();
                } else {
                  openMenu(_key);
                }
              },
              child: buildDraggable("Draggable", content));
        },
        onWillAccept: (data) {
          return true;
        },
        onAccept: (data) {
          _swapData(content.num, data);
        },
        onLeave: (data) {},
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: buildDragTarget(data[0])),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: buildDragTarget(data[1])),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it's solved.

1. Wrap `Draggable` widget with `Listener` instead of `GestureDetector`.
2. In `LongPressDraggable`, set a function that opens a menu　to `onDragStarted` .
3. In `Listener`, set a function to get beginning position to `onPointerDown`.
4. In `Listener`, set a function, calculate distance between beginning position and current position and hide menu if the distance are more than 20, to `onPointerMove`,

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SampleContainer()));

class SampleContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class Content {
  final num;
  final IconData icon;

  Content(this.num, this.icon);
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  Size? buttonSize;
  Offset? buttonPosition;
  bool isMenuOpen = false;
  Offset beginningDragPosition = Offset.zero; //add
  Offset currentDragPosition = Offset.zero; //add

  List<Content> data = [
    Content(0, Icons.filter_1),
    Content(1, Icons.filter_2),
  ];

  _swapData(int index1, var index2) {
    Content data1 = data[index1];
    Content data2 = data[index2];
    data[index1] = data2;
    data[index2] = data1;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void openMenu(GlobalKey _key) {
    findButton(_key);
    _overlayEntry = _overlayEntryBuilder();
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlayEntry!);
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  void closeMenu() {
    _overlayEntry!.remove();
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  findButton(GlobalKey _key) {
    RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    buttonSize = renderBox.size;
    buttonPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }

  LongPressDraggable buildDraggable(
          String name, Content content, GlobalKey _key) =>
      new LongPressDraggable(
        key: _key,
        data: content.num,
        maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
        hapticFeedbackOnStart: true,
        child: Icon(
          content.icon,
          size: 90,
        ),
        onDragStarted: () {
          if (!isMenuOpen) {
            openMenu(_key);
          }
        },
        feedback: Icon(
          content.icon,
          size: 90,
        ),
      );

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntryBuilder() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: buttonPosition!.dy + buttonSize!.height,
          left: buttonPosition!.dx,
          width: buttonSize!.width,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  DragTarget buildDragTarget(Content content) => new DragTarget(
        builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
          GlobalKey _key = LabeledGlobalKey(content.num.toString());

          return Listener(
              //add
              onPointerDown: (details) {
                if (isMenuOpen) closeMenu();
                beginningDragPosition = details.position;
              },
              onPointerMove: (details) {
                currentDragPosition = Offset(
                  details.position.dx - beginningDragPosition.dx,
                  details.position.dy - beginningDragPosition.dy,
                );
                if (currentDragPosition.distance > 20) {
                  if (isMenuOpen) closeMenu();
                }
              },
              child: buildDraggable("Draggable", content, _key));
        },
        onWillAccept: (data) {
          return true;
        },
        onAccept: (data) {
          _swapData(content.num, data);
        },
        onLeave: (data) {},
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      //add
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        if (isMenuOpen) closeMenu();
      },
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: buildDragTarget(data[0])),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: buildDragTarget(data[1])),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```